# getting Cannot read property getDate of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, date

I am sending date through backend node js by using timestamps but when i try to access date functions like getDate() in the front end it is giving me undefined. createdAt object is printing the whole value correctly but i want to access the date and time separatly. I also want to convert this time to local gmt+5 time. How can I do that?

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Slip = (props) => {
    const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);

    const loadOrderData = useCallback(async () => {
        axios
            .get(
                "http://localhost:4000/api/orders/one/" +
                    props.history.location.state.orderid
            )
            .then((res) => {
                setOrder(res.data);
            });
    }, [props]);

    const onPrintClick = () => {
        window.print();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadOrderData();
    }, [loadOrderData]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <br />
            <div className="container">
                <h4>Danny's Fast Food & Pizza</h4>
                <h5>Reciept</h5>
                <span>
                    <h6>{order.createdAt.getDate()}</h6>
                </span>
                <button className="btn btn-dark w-25" onClick={onPrintClick}>
                    Print
                </button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Slip;
```

Comment: 2 Observations
You have initialised ```order``` with an Array and you are using this as an object.
Your return doesn't have any check if the created date is not available dont render it. That means until the API response is with you you are not supposed to render the component.

Comment: I tried changing it to a json object and also tried a loading object which will not allow it render before loading the order

Comment: Working for me just posted an answer . See if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";

const Slip = (props) => {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});

  const loadOrderData = useCallback(async () => {
    // Your API call to get the date
    let letDummyOrder = {
      createdAt: new Date()
    }
    setOrder(letDummyOrder)
  }, [props]);

  const onPrintClick = () => {
    window.print();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadOrderData();
  }, [loadOrderData]);

  if (!order.createdAt) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <br />
      <div className="container">
        <h4>Danny's Fast Food & Pizza</h4>
        <h5>Reciept</h5>
        <span>
          <h6>Date : {order.createdAt.getDate()}</h6>
        </span>
        <button className="btn btn-dark w-25" onClick={onPrintClick}>
          Print
                </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Slip;
```

Alternatively if you want everything to render but the date
Replace

```
<h6>{order.createdAt.getDate()}</h6>
```

with

```
<h6>{order.createdAt?.getDate()}</h6>
```

Comment: now I am getting getDate is not a function. I think my problem is the data from the backend is not coming as a Date object it is coming as a string.

Comment: ok.. if my answer help you please upvote and accept ... happy coding